# Rails: Update parent attribute when (has_many) child record(s) is/are updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I have the following structure

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_lines, inverse_of: :order, validate: false, autosave: true
end

class OrderLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :order_lines, touch: true, counter_cache: :line_count
end
```

I would like a parent(`Order`) attribute to be updated when the children(`OrderLine`) records are updated. Let's say `Order Total` is to be updated when the `OrderLine` Price/Quantity is updated.

I could add an `after_save/commit` callback on the `OrderLine` level OR add `after_commit` callback(because of `touch: true`) on the `Order` level to calculate and update the `total`.

However, when the number of lines is huge(more than 100), it executes callback on each line update, which is having performance impacts.
Also, there are feature flows where individual/multiple lines get updated without updating the parent(Order) record. So I do need to have the callback on line level as well to update the total in such scenarios.

Is there a way to update the parent attribute(total) here in a more performant way?

Comment: If you just need to update the total number of items of children I think counter cache would help.

Comment: I need to update some other attribute which can be derived via some calculation.